# Nokia 220 s30+ Development

Tags: nokia

I just want to ask that how can i develop apps for Nokia 220 which has s30+ platform. Is there any way to develop apps for this or not?

Comment: I see you've accepted the other answer. Have you managed to find a way to develop apps? If so, pleas update that answer with information on how to do it. (The mre.mediatek.com link is still dead.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S30+ is MRE from Mediatek, see mre.mediatek.com.
There you can find a development system.
However, for the Microsoft handsets you need signing,
which i dont know how to achieve.

Comment: That link appears to be dead. A Google search for "MRE mediatek" turned up several results, including http://mre.software.informer.com/; I don't know whether that particular link is appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

It appears that the answer is no.

In spite of the name, [S30+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_30%2B) is not related to [S30](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_30).

Microsoft's [specifications page](http://www.microsoft.com/en/mobile/phone/220/specifications/) for the Nokia 220 mention a handful of built-in applications (browser, calendar, contacts, alarm clock, "native games", etc.), but says nothing about installable applications.

This FAQ: [How do I update the software on my Series 30+ phone?](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/mobile/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA144006) discusses a "Software Recovery Tool" that runs on a computer; it erases all personal content on the phone.

This doesn't prove that it's impossible to install additional applications, but it strongly suggests that it's at least not supported.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for being late for nearly 7 years (I was a kid 7 years ago :D)

[Here](https://github.com/UstadMobile/ustadmobile-mre/issues/2#issuecomment-561627649) is the link to a comment on Github where a man post a copy of MRE SDK 3.0.

From his comment:

> Yes it is removed from his server bit I have copy of it on my google
> drive I give you link
>
> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KIh3VrOIAYLVw5cOf2_uPQvJbOmT6MyC/view?usp=drivesdk

and

> If you want any other software that are missing you may found here
> https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=12ohq-7V0_02QQX9Kjf1m6YRWHO9-JpPy

If the link is broken, leave a comment and I will fix it :)

I also made a copy of it in my [repo](https://github.com/raspiduino/mre-sdk).

Hope it helps.