# Where to get MRE SDK for Nokia 225?

Tags: api, sdk, nokia

Is there any site from which I can download MRE SDK? I just registered on [mre](http://mre.mediatek.com/en/sdk/3.0), but after four days I still get

> You have been registered, but need wait 1-3 days for account review,
>   after the virified process can be downloaded.

I am not sure if this page is still active - Copyright notice for 2012. I tried to find "mre sdk" on share servers and on microsoft, but no luck.
I would just like to test my Nokia 225.

Comment: are you able to get the skd?

Comment: Wow that website is down now.

Comment: Late to the party, but here's my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72500497/15365513